# Почему в цикле forEach this указывает на объект Window

Tags: javascript, foreach

Простой цикл в конструкторе «класса»:

```
function TRoute(attributes) {
  var attributes = attributes || {};

  this.waypoints = [];

  attributes.waypoints.forEach(function(waypoint_text, i){
    this.waypoints.push({text: waypoint_text})
  });
};
```

После этого при вызове конструктора получаю ошибку

```
TypeError: 'undefined' is not an object (evaluating 'this.waypoints.push')
```

Дебагером выяснил, что внутри цикла `forEach` переменная `this` указывает на глобальный объект (в случае с браузером — `Window`). Вопрос — почему?

К слову, мне нужно, чтобы `this` указывал на объект `TRoute` (как в строчке)

```
this.waypoints = [];
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Как известно](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/this), в JS `this` не привязывается к объекту, а зависит от контекста вызова.

Если функция вызывается как свойство объекта, `this` в ней будет указывать на объект, вызвавший её, в отличных случаях `this == window`, а если указан строгий режим (`"use strict"`), то и вовсе `this === undefined`.

Так как внутре `array.prototype.forEach()` функция вызывается независимо от объекта, то и получается, что у Вас контекст в ней равен, так как не установлен строгий режим, `window`.

Распространенной практикой является сохранение нужного контекста в отдельной переменной:

```
var me = this;
var self = this;
var that = this;
```

Бывает удобно использовать его именно так, ведь тогда можно делать с этим контекстом что угодно и где угодно, не задумываясь, что же будет значить `this` в этой ситуации (надо будет только подумать в самый первый раз, выполнив это присвоение).

Тогда в Вашем случае можно написать так:

```
function TRoute(attributes) {
    var me = this;

    me.waypoints = [];

    attributes.waypoints.forEach(function(waypoint_text, i){
        me.waypoints.push({text: waypoint_text})
    });
};
```

Однако, если у функции есть возможность передать контекст вызова, а у [`Array.prototype.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) она есть, то надо использовать её:

```
attributes.waypoints.forEach(
    function(waypoint_text, i){
        this.waypoints.push({text: waypoint_text})
    },
    me
);
```

Comment: > надо использовать её... Так в результате и сделал. А не подскажите, почему это лучше, чем с `me`?

Comment: @installero, на самом деле просто универсальней (предчувствие говорит, что в производительности разницы не будет), Вы можете использовать одну и туже конструкцию для разных случаев, просто меняя второй аргумент. Я считаю, что если что-то предоставляет удобный API, и ты используешь это что-то, то надо использовать его по полной.

Answer (score 0):

Выяснилось, что чтобы передать нужный контекст у `forEach` есть второй параметр:

```
attributes.waypoints.forEach(function(waypoint_text, i){
  this.waypoints.push({text: waypoint_text})
}, this);
```

Но, может, у кого есть лучше идеи?

Comment: Подождать пока все браузеры имплементируют [for...of](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/for...of)